# How to Access Timeline for gotoAndStop via External Class [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to go frame-label "5", when my hero hits an enemy object. So I want to know how to use `gotoAndStop` from my external custom class to control Stage timeline.

So how exactly could I access `gotoAndStop` and what's the syntax to use for running that `gotoAndStop` method from the custom class.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to write in your `if` statement:

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop("5");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.

A simple solution could be to pass the main timeline to the external class, like so:

```
public function ExternalClass(timeline:MovieClip)
```

With this as the constructor of your class, you get a reference to the movieclip that should be played.

Another, better solution would be to execute the hittest on the main time line or dispatch an Event from the class that does the hittest.